# Strange problems while setting foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

Database: Oracle 10.1 on os:xp2002

I am setting foreign key in employee table but it I get an error

> no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

I am using following queries for creating the tables.

**Department table:**

```
create table department(
d_name  varchar2(10) not null,
d_no_of_employees number(4));
```

**Employee table:**

```
create table employee(
e_id        number(4)       ,
e_name      varchar2(30)        not null,
e_f_name    varchar2(30)        not null,
e_desg      varchar2(20)        not null,
e_address   varchar2(50)        not null,
e_phone_no  number(12)      not null,
e_salary    number(10)      not null,
e_house_rent number(6)    not null,
e_conv_allow number(6)    not null,
e_email     varchar2(50)        not null    unique,
d2_name     varchar2(10)        not null,       
e_hire_month  number(2) not null,
e_hire_year  number(4) not null,
constraint e_id_pk primary key(e_id),
constraint d2_name_fk foreign key(d2_name) references department(d_name))
;
```

Any solution please.

Comment: thanks to all of you.but while working with oracle 9i above quries were working fine.could anyone please explain its reason?

Comment: It has never been possible in Oracle to create a foreign key that doesn't reference a primary or unique key in the parent table,

Answer (score 5):

the foreign key must be a primary or unique key in the other table.

Comment: thanks.but while working with oracle 9i above quries were working fine.could you please explain its reason?

Comment: @Adnan - Are you sure that there wasn't at least a unique index on `D_NAME` in the old database?  A foreign key can reference a parent that is declared as unique though it should really only reference primary keys.

Comment: @Adrian - In the 9i version, was there a separate `alter table` command that added the PK after the `department` table was created?

Comment: @Alex Poole:No there was not any special   alter table    command that added the PK after the department table was created.

Comment: @Justin Cave:Yes i am sure that there wasn't at laeast a unique index on D_NAME in the old database.

Answer (score 2):

Make d_name PRIMARY KEY of Department table.

```
create table department(
d_name  varchar2(10) not null,
d_no_of_employees number(4),
constraint d_name_pk primary key(d_name));
```

And then create the Employee table.

Answer (score 2):

From what you've posted you don't seem to have a primary key on the `department` table. Something like:

```
create table department(
d_name  varchar2(10) not null,
d_no_of_employees number(4)
constraint department_pk primary key(d_name));
```

Or after creation:

```
alter table department
add constraint department_pk primary key(d_name)
...
```